# Additional <BR>s When Using LibrarEE For Custom Emails

Tags: ee2, email

I'm working my way through customising system notifications - new blog post etc.

If I send my HTML through the `tools > communicate` option it comes through looking fine. If I send it as a regular notification via LibraEE is comes through with a bunch of `<br>` tags all through it. Sometimes 8 `<br>` in a row. And sometimes it's adding in `<td><br></td>`.

LibrarEE has a preview function and the email looks fine there.

Can anyone suggest where to go to try and find where to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

EE2.5.5

LibrarEE 1.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this - turn off the setting for :

Enable parsing of HTML user notification emails

This will fix the issue.

Regards,

Carl

Comment: Hi Carl, That did fix the <br> issue but it seems I can't used GVs anymore - is that expect behaviour?